# How to initialize sap.ushell.bootstrap in SAPUI5 app?

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I try to use [this solution](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3538527) to display user id in SAPUI5 application.

The needed snippet is:

```
sap.ushell.Container.getService("UserInfo").getId()
```

`sap.ushell` doesn't contains any of service methods, described on [this page](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ushell.html), it contains only UI-specific entries.
My HCP account doesn't have any ABAP JS needed to initialize the `sap.ushell` like it is described here:

> For convenience, platform-specific bootstrap code is available and can
>   be easily included (before the SAPUI5 bootstrap) by a corporate shell
>   as follows:

```
<script> src="/sap/public/bc/ui5_ui5/resources/sap/ushell_abap/bootstrap/abap.js"></script>
```

> This bootstrap code will automatically defer the initialization of
>   SAPUI5 until the container is available. This is the preferred way of
>   bootstrapping the Unified Shell.

```
<script src=".../resources/sap/ushell_abap/bootstrap/abap.js"></script>
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src=".../sap-ui-core.js"></script>
```

How to initialize the  sap.ushell?
My index.html has the following bootstrap:

```
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.34.9/resources/sap-ui-

        core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons, sap.ui.table,sap.ui.ux3,sap.ushell"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
                data-sap-ui-preload="async"
                >

            </script>

                  <script>
                     sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {....
                     });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the id of the current user (logged in at the HCP) doing this:

1. Add the respective service entry in your neo-app.json file:

   ```
   "welcomeFile": "index.html",
   "routes": [
   ...
   {
   "path": "/services/userapi",
   "target": {
   "type": "service",
   "name": "userapi"
   }
   ...
   ```
2. Set the user model wherever you want (e.g. in your component.js):

   ```
   // set user model
   var userModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
   userModel.loadData("/services/userapi/currentUser", null, false);
   this.setModel(userModel, "userapi");
   ```

In the userapi model you then have access to some user information including the user id.